# C# writing to file using UTF8

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, utf-8

I have this simple code:

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(path + kat + "/" + namec, true, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    sw.WriteLine(namex + "," + address + "," + web + "," + email + "," + phone + "," + linksx + "," + transport);
}
```

I using Selenium Web Driver to download data from Denmark website, example link:http://www.visitdenmark.dk/da/danmark/danhostel-roenne-gdk614558

Then I store it in .csv file, but still I have characters like this Ă instead of this ø. As you can see I set `Encoding.UTF8` Also it becoming more interesting when I set bool append to false, then everything is normal, but it does not help me because I need to append that file with new data. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>You should use windows-1252(or, `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`) instead of UTF-8, for Danish.</del>

---

EDIT:

It was a missing BOM issue causing Excel unable to read the file properly.

```
// notice we are creating a new file here
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path, false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    // Add a BOM in the beginning of the file
    var preamble = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble();
    writer.BaseStream.Write(preamble, 0, preamble.Length);

    // write data...
    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", "Danhostel Rønne", "Arsenalvej 12 3700 Rønne"));
}

// when you write the same file again, you don't need to append the BOM again
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path, true, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    // write more data...
    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", "Danhostel Rønne", "Arsenalvej 12 3700 Rønne"));
}
```

Comment: Still same http://prntscr.com/f16v7b when I do `MessageBox.Show(namex);` before inserting in .csv file it showing me normal chars so before insertion everything is normal. Any clue ?

Comment: @mdieod could you test if this code generates the correct result? https://pastebin.com/L947k1Nw

Comment: What happens when you open your csv file with notepad instead of Excel? If you go to Data->From Text in Excel and if you have the wrong encoding selected then it reads the bits wrong and shows incorrect characters.

Comment: @Quantic When I try to import data from text then it automatically set Windows (ANSI) and works normal. I still don't see how this can help me ?

Comment: @mdieod It seems that Excel is opening the file incorrectly. Can you test this code. I've added a BOM in the beginning of the file. https://pastebin.com/dYPUxRPn

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Still does not work, I just change append to true and ran it with your BOM and same result.

Comment: @mdieod No, you have to run the script as is. Create a new project and run it. The goal is to test if adding the BOM solves your issue or not, and it has to be the *VERT FIRST* bytes of the file.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Ok, I just created new project and I pasted the whole code and still same issue... http://prntscr.com/f17npu

Comment: Interesting I just changed it to UTF8 in your code and it works right now, you said before it should be windows-1252, but why now it works with UTF8 ?

Comment: So, it was fixed with UTF-8 with BOM?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Yes, Thank you very much for helping me, it matters a lot to me. I will accept  your answer. Again THANK YOU!